# Using [i] in a loop to point at an element gives me unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Not sure how to do this otherwise...
But this is what I'm trying to do:

I have an array of radio boxes

```
<div id="xrowcont_0">
    <input type="radio" name="13_641" value="a" id="13_641_form_a" ><label for="13_641_form_a"><span></span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="13_641" value="b" id="13_641_form_b" checked="checked"><label for="13_641_form_b"><span></span></label>
    <div id="xmod_mach_list_0" style="display:none;">BOO1</div>
</div>

<div id="xrowcont_1">
    <input type="radio" name="13_642" value="a" id="13_642_form_a"><label for="13_642_form_a"><span></span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="13_642" value="b" id="13_642_form_b"><label for="13_642_form_b"><span></span></label>
    <div id="xmod_mach_list_1" style="display:none;">BOO2</div>
</div>

... ++++
```

And the idea is that when you select radio box "B" in the `<div id="xrowcont_0">`, it unhides `<div id="xmod_mach_list_1"` beside each row.

Here is the js:

Lets say we have 13 rows...

```
for (var i=0;i<13;i++) {    
    var a1 = "'#xrowcont_" + [i] + " input[type=radio]'";
    var a2 = "'#xrowcont_" + [i] + " input:checked'";

    console.log(a1);
    console.log(a2); // these show up just fine.

    $(a1).on( "click", function() { // but here it breaks.
        var state = $(a2).val();
        if (state == "b") {
            $('#xmod_mach_list_' + [i] ).css('opacity',0).show().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
            console.log("Show Button");

        } else { 
            $('#xmod_mach_list_' + [i] ).animate({ opacity: 0} , 200);
            setTimeout(function () {$('#xmod_mach_list_' + [i] ).hide(); }, 200); 
            console.log("Hide Button");
        };    
    });
}
```

It gives me `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#xrowcont_0 input[type=radio]'`, although that is what I want to be populated in the `... $(a1).on( "click", function() {...` and so on part.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't `radio` be enclosed with quotes in `a1`?

Comment: @Renan It doesn't need to be; you'd only *have* to include it in double quotes if the attribute value contained spaces (or if you wanted to avoid escaping special characters).

Comment: Brackets or no brackets, it doesnt mater im afraid :/. The script works if I just put a1 = "'#xrowcont_0 input[type=radio]'". So yea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your strings `a1` and `a2` are invalid jQuery selectors. Contrary to what you think you **don't** want their values to include the single quotes, so take those out.

It should be:

```
var a1 = "#xrowcont_" + [i] + " input[type=radio]";
var a2 = "#xrowcont_" + [i] + " input:checked";
```

You wouldn't do:

```
$("'#xrowcont_0 input[type=radio]'").on(...);
```

when working with jQuery, so you also shouldn't put them inside the strings when declaring selectors as separate variables. The selector itself is not `'#foo'`, it's `#foo`. The single or double quotes are only there to signify that it's a string when being passed to the jQuery object - your variables are *already* strings though.

---

There's a separate, unrelated issue with that code to do with the `for` loop. You're delaying execution of some code using both event handlers and `setTimeout`, but you're using `i` (the index variable for your `for` loop) inside that function. Due to the way variables are scoped in JavaScript that delayed execution will use the value of `i` for the *last* iteration of the loop.

To get around this you'll need to create a new closure (a new scope for variables) using an immediately invoked function expression:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        // i here is a different variable to i outside
        // it's passed, and maintains, the value for this iteration of the loop
        ... // your loop code
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: True. Thank you. I tried that before and It didnt work. But now I know that I was wrong and it did work because... the `a2` only passes the last value of `i` to the `var state`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @VytautasPaulauskas Yes, create a closure using an immediately invoked function expression. I'll update my answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the brackets. `[i]` is an array containing `i` as its only item.

You should also note that using `i` in a `setTimeout` will cause problems thanks to the magic of closures. Consider forming you loop like so:

```
for(i ......) { (function(i) {
    ...
})(i); }
```

Comment: The square brackets are unnecessary, but not causing the problem. Since it only has a single element calling `.toString()` on the array will just return the value of `i` as a string. The issue is that they're including single quotes as part of their string, which isn't a valid jQuery selector.